# Вывести отрезки времени по пол часа

Tags: время, php

Здравствуйте, вот есть код

```
if ($minute > '0' ) {
    $hour = $hour + 1;
}
while ($hour <= 24) {
    <tr><td><?=$hour++?> Часов</td></tr>

}
```

Выводит отрезки времени по часу, а как сделать, если нужно чтобы выводило по пол часа? То есть не

```
1 2 3
```

а

```
1 1:30 2 2:30
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$hhmm = new DateTime( date('H').':00' );
while( $hhmm->format('H') > 0 )
{
    print( $hhmm->format("H:i\n" ) );
    $hhmm->modify('+30 minutes');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо заменил весь огромный код на это, осталось проверку сделать, что если 2:12 округляло до следущего врмени.